# more score for searches closer to the beginning of the sentence (script_exception)

Tags: elasticsearch

how do I give more score for searches closer to the beginning of the sentence

```
query: ipad

phrase2: Apple other word Ipad pro 1
phrase1: Apple pro ipad
phrase2: Apple pro 1
phrase3: Ipad pro 1

GET _search
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "name" : {
              "query" : "ipad"
            }
            ** (....) **
        }
    }
}
```

applying to query order by score result:

```
phrase3
phrase1
phrase2
```

I did this script but it does not work

```
GET /store/products/_search
{
   "_source": "name", 
    "query": {

      "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "query_string" : {
              "query": "apple"
              , "fields":[  
                  "name"
               ]
        }
        },
        "functions": [
         {  
               "script_score":{  
                  "script": "def termInfo = [];  termInfo = _index['name'].get('apple',_POSITIONS); positions = [];score = 0;for (pos in termInfo) { if(positions.contains(pos.position)){ next;} score = score +  pos.position;positions.add(pos.position)}return positions.size();"
               }
            }
        ],"boost_mode":"replace"
      }
    }
}
```

I can not access the variables "_index ..."
Running the script displays this error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "compile error",
        "script_stack": [
          "... rmInfo = [];  termInfo = _index['name'].get('apple ...",
          "                             ^---- HERE"
        ], ...
```

My version of eslastic search is 5.0

Comment: See whether https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/modules-advanced-scripting.html helps. In particular, the `_POSITION` gives you term positions, which seems relevant.

Comment: I can not access the variables "_index ..."
Running the script displays this error

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the "inline" property as in the ES5 documentation
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-script-score

Try this

```
"script_score":{  
                  "script": {
"inline": "def termInfo = [];  termInfo = _index['name'].get('apple',_POSITIONS); positions = [];score = 0;for (pos in termInfo) { if(positions.contains(pos.position)){ next;} score = score +  pos.position;positions.add(pos.position)}return positions.size();"
               }
}
```